# Tomcat's behaviour when two simultaneous requests come from same ip

Tags: java, tomcat

When i try to run 2 wget commands simultaneously to my server (http://myserver), looks like tomcat allocates two threads to process them. But i believe when tomcat receives two simultaneously from same ip address, it will not create a new thread for processing the second request as it considers both the requests come from same session.

If i want to check if both the threads are same or different, is using thread.getId() the only way? I think this id may be reused for new threads. Is there any unique property of the thread existing to check its identity other than threadid?

Comment: afaik, tomcat processes each request in a separate thread. Refer [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to never rely on threads to identify their source. There are **no Servlet spec guarantees** about threads, and newer Servlet spec implementations make use of NIO. You are skating on a thin ice.

Answer (score 1):

Web servers will almost always assign multiple threads (or processes) to multiple simultaneous requests, since the  client can work faster when it does not have to wait for each response.

Newer servers may use asynchronous IO (nio), however, and a single thread can simultaneously serve many clients.

Yes, *Thread.getId()* is a way of identifying threads.

Session IDs are the mechanism used to identify requests from a single client.

The IP address is not a good way to do that, since multiple machines can expose the same IP when hiding behind a NAT.

Comment: Thanks. But i guess JVM may reuse the id of one thread to a second thread if the first had died.

Comment: Yes, Java servers often  reuse the same thread for multiple requests, after a thread has finished its loop (not "died"); but not simultaneously . (Though Java asynch IO [nio] would allow that.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Tomcat will always create a new thread of execution irrespective of whether it comes from the same IP or not. In case, the client application running on the particular IP has a mechanism to send across the session-id, then Tomcat will simply associate the same session context with the request thread [making it stateful].

in your case, you'll need to customise wget to hold on to the **session-id** [the Tomcat web-app might send it across through a cookie or as a url parameter - `jsessionid`]. wget will then need to send it back with the subsequent requests [url rewrite and include the `jsessionid` parameter, or exchange cookies]. this way Tomcat will be able to treat each request coming from a unique client instance and associate a state with it.

Comment: Thanks, got it. I just used to wget to test tomcat's behaviour on 2 simultaneous request from same m/c. Also, if i want to know the thread's identity, i may not use thread.getId() as the ID can be reused. Any other way to check this?

Comment: It sound like you're trying to use the Tomcat processing thread as a way of persisting state for a given client? Tomcat will use a thread pool and reuse those threads. The only way to persist state is to provide it in the request parameters or use a cookie to identify a session.

Comment: as indicated, find a way to extract and exchange the `jsessionid`

Comment: Am not trying to use thread for data persistence. Now understood that, irrespective of the source of the requests, tomcat allocates new threads for processing; for same source, context is shared

Thank you.